# How to filter locations by custom area in django?

Tags: django, geolocation, postgis

I’m to allow user to draw his custom area on frontend (flutter) and pass it to backend (django +postgis) which must return list of `PointField`s thats are lies inside the curve. So, in which format should I pass the curve to the backen and how do I properly filter the places queryset?
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you've got a model defined as

```
class Place(models.Model):
    location = PointField()
```

You should be able to use [the `within` lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/#within) to retrieve all places with a location contained in the user provided geometry

```
Place.objects.filter(location__within=geometry)
```

I suggest you export the user selection as GeoJSON from the frontend and `POST` it to the backend. On the Django side you should be able to [create a `GEOSGeometry` from the provided data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/gis/geos/#geosgeometry)

```
geometry = GEOSGeometry(request.POST['selection'])
Place.objects.filter(location__within=geometry)
```

You'll want to validate the `selection` is valid GeoJSON but this should at least get you started.